# Unity video player audio skipping

Tags: ipad, unity-game-engine, video-player

***Edit: This was a known bug, and was fixed in Unity 2018.1, details can be found [here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-videoplayer-vp8-video-sound-plays-faster-than-video).***

I have a .mp4 video, with H264 video encoding and AAC audio encoding.

I'm loading this video using a Video Player node to load it onto a texture, with a seperate audio source for playing the audio.

I initialise my video like so:

```
_videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.VideoClip;
_videoPlayer.clip = introVideo;

//Set Audio Output to AudioSource
_videoPlayer.audioOutputMode = VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource;
//Assign the Audio from Video to AudioSource to be played
_videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(0, true);

_videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource(0,_audio);
_audio.volume = 1f;

_videoPlayer.Prepare();

while (!_videoPlayer.isPrepared)
{
    yield return null;
}

_videoPlayer.Play();
```

This method works fine when running on a Mac. However, when I create a build and deploy it to my iPad, the audio is jumpy, and will finish significantly ahead of the video.

Is there something I can do to stop the audio from skipping?

Comment: How large is the video, whats the resolution, what is the bitrate of the audio. It may be that you are just using to much system resource.

Comment: Must call `VideoPlayer.Prepare()` and must wait for `videoPlayer.isPrepared()` to be true before playing the video.

Comment: The video is 112mb, 1m 10s long, 1080p, and has a bitrate of 12mb/s. I've updated my question to reflect the changes i made regarding using prepare, but even after the changes I'm having exactly the same issues. I don't think this is a duplicate of the question linked, as I'm not having a problem actually playing the audio, the problem is it skips, and plays too fast.

Comment: Turns out this was a unity bug that was fixed in the latest beta version (2018.1b), as documented here: (https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-videoplayer-vp8-video-sound-plays-faster-than-video) Consider unmarking this question so I can put this as an answer?